# object' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no extension method 'Save' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

i need to add barcode pic to Barcodemat column in crpReport like this

```
r["BarcodeMat"] = ImageToByte2(bar.Encode(typebq, data, w, hh));
```

and this is my function ImageToByte2

```
 private byte[] ImageToByte2(object img)
{
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Close();
        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

i have error in

```
img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

The error said 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no extension method 'Save' accepting first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: Unless `img` is `System.Drawing.Image` type, then you can use [`Save(Stream, ImageFormat)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_IO_Stream_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_). Not sure what is the type that the value returned by `bar.Encode(typebq, data, w, hh)`. Please further clarify. Thanks.

Comment: typebq = BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128;
 BarcodeLib.Barcode bar = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
                int w = 290;
                int hh = 55;
                BarcodeLib.TYPE typebq = new BarcodeLib.TYPE();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [barnhill/barcodelib `Barcode` (Line 336)](https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib/blob/a85d66d3487398b2675eb3eb2c62e8d32c41ceea/BarcodeStandard/BarcodeLib.cs#L336),

```cs
public Image Encode(TYPE iType, string StringToEncode, int Width, int Height)
```

The method is returned with `Image` type.

---

Hence, change `img` parameter to `Image` type.

```cs
using System.Drawing;

private byte[] ImageToByte2(Image img)
{
    ...
}
```

---

### References

[GitHub - barnhill/barcodelib: C# Barcode Image Generation Library (Example section)](https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib#example)